# How to import data of google sheet file to other google sheet file with Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm wondering how to import google sheet data to other sheet files by using apps script.

This is the sheet1 in file A.
[image]

And this it the sheet2 in file B.
[image]

In this situation, I want to import column A,C,D data as each Sku number.
The result what I want to get will be like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert from the upper 2 images in your question to the bottom image in your question.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, the value of columns "B" is the key for searching values. Using this key, the array is created using the retrieved values from column "B" of Sheet2. And, the created array is put to Sheet2.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [sheet1, sheet2] = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // 2. Retrieve values from Sheet1 and create an object for searching values.
  const obj = sheet1.getRange("A2:D" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, {[r[1]]: r}), {});

  // 3. Retrieve values from Sheet2 and create an array for putting to Sheet2.
  const values = sheet2.getRange("A2:D" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues().flatMap(r => [obj[r[1]] || r]);

  // 4. Put the array to Sheet2.
  sheet2.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from Sheet1 and put to the new values to the Sheet2 by searching the values from Sheet1 and Sheet2. By this, your goal can be achieved.

#### Note:

- When the order of the header row is different between Sheet1 and Sheet2, how about the following sample script? In this script, the search header row can be declared. And, by using the declared search-header value, the values are retrieved from Sheet1 and create an array and put the array to Sheet2.

  ```
    function myFunction2() {
      const search = "Sku"; // Please set the search header value. This value from your question.

      // 1. Retrieve sheets.
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const [sheet1, sheet2] = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

      // 2. Retrieve values from Sheet1 and create an object for searching values.
      const [h1, ...v1] = sheet1.getRange("A1:D" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
      const n1 = h1.indexOf(search);
      const obj = v1.reduce((o1, r) => Object.assign(o1, {[r[n1]]: h1.reduce((o2, h, j) => (o2[h] = r[j], o2), {})}), {});

      // 3. Retrieve values from Sheet2 and create an array for putting to Sheet2.
      const [h2, ...v2] = sheet2.getRange("A1:D" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues();
      const n2 = h2.indexOf(search);
      const values = v2.map(r => obj[r[n2]] ? h2.map(h => obj[r[n2]][h]) : r);

      // 4. Put the array to Sheet2.
      sheet2.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)